# what is ^K in output of cat -v ? For use in mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, replace, whitespace, cat

I have run cat -v on a file, see ^K where I was expecting to see some kind of whitespace, but don't know how to translate that code into something I can use to find and replace the character in MySQL.

Context: I have a mysql field that appears to have a newline at the end, as when I query it, the output wraps around.

```
    select t_unid_contact
    ,      concat('"',t_phone,'"')
    ,      t_phone 
    from contacts_june_2013 
    where T_UNID_Contact = 'CN726181';

    +----------------+-------------------------+-------------+
    | t_unid_contact | concat('"',t_phone,'"') | t_phone     |
    +----------------+-------------------------+-------------+
    | CN726181       | "4155551212
                                  "           | 4155551212
                                                           |
    +----------------+-------------------------+-------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried these WHERE clauses, to try to identify rows with the hidden character, but got no results:

```
    where t_phone like '%\n%'
    where t_phone like '%\r%'
    where t_phone like '%\r\n%'
    where t_phone like '%\k%'
    where t_phone regexp '[\r]'
    where t_phone regexp '[\k]'
    where t_phone regexp '[\n]'
    where t_phone regexp '[\r\n]'
```

I output a problem row into a csv and ran this to look at it; here is the output:

```
    cat -v testwhitespace.csv 
    "CN726181","4155551212^K"
```

Does anyone know how I can identify that whitespace character in my table, in such a way that I can use replace() to get rid of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^K` is the control code for a vertical/line tabulation character, [U+000B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/).

```
REPLACE(my_column, _utf8 x'0b', '')
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I'm still trying to figure out how to use that in a WHERE clause, though, to find rows containing that record. Not that that is as important as doing the actual replace. But I should get the syntax figured out.

Comment: @user2616155: One way would be `WHERE my_column LIKE CONCAT('%', _utf8 x'0b', '%')`, but it won't be very efficient!

Comment: That works very nicely, thank you. I'm working to clean up data, not writing production code, so this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, ^K is a vertical tab, as previously stated.
As ^k == 11th char == b in hexdec

You state that you are looking at a file.

sed -e 's/\x0b/ /g' file

should strip them for a space.

If you want to use SQL, try \x0b on the where clause.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to use utf8 codes in the WHERE clause yet, but I used this kludgey workaround: update contacts_june_2013
set t_phone = REPLACE(t_phone, _utf8 x'0b', '')
where t_phone <> REPLACE(t_phone, _utf8 x'0b', '');